How to save the information of the current tab and site of origin in the correct way
In my chrome extension I'm trying to save the current tab displayed with information deriving from the URL page from which I activated the extension. If I try to open another URL and then the extension again I would like it to save the current tab and the new URL.
For example my to be is:

open www.site1.com and after that my extension
open another tab with www.site2.com and after than my extension
if i use the first or the second tab extension i want to retrive the information abount site1 or site2 depends which extension tab current display.

I can't properly retrieve or save this information in my extension service worker.
I try to set the tabId and url in the chrome storage from my service worker (background.js) and after i try to retrive this information in the page after a button click. but didn't work.
Maybe there is some step i must to do ?
Sorry for my english.
Thanks

What do you mean by "activated the extension": do you have it activated in the content script or by clicking on the extension icon and bringing up the popup?
